# Does Cloud Run keep pre-existing connections open when a revision's traffic percent is set to 0?

Tags: google-cloud-run

If I have a Cloud Run revision (let's call it revision A) that's serving 100% of traffic, and I swap 100% of traffic to another revision (revision B), will in-flight connections that were being served by revision A be killed immediately, or will they have an opportunity to finish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Run will continue to handle on-going requests on the existing instances of the old [revision](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/managing/revisions). The instances on the old revision will only [shutdown once all requests are handled and be idle for about 15 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling#idle-instance). Only the new requests will be routed to the new revision.

Comment: I agree with your answer but the link provided does not provide details on new revisions.

Comment: Added the link to the Cloud Run revision official doc.